# Retrieve account name with the NEW Google Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I set up the authorization process for Google Play Services as described under https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

Now that the user has authorized the app I want to retrieve the account name. But I can't find any method in the API (http://developer.android.com/reference/gms-packages.html) that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you already have [QUICKSTART](https://github.com/googledrive/android-quickstart) or [DEMO](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos), or something similar up-and-running, so I will refer to these 2 examples. In the [BaseDemoActivity.java](https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo/BaseDemoActivity.java) code, you'll notice that account selection is invoked when connection fails,

```
@Override public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
  ...
  result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
  ...
}
```

... and it comes back in onActivityResult(). I just grab the intent data and get the KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, it is the selected email. The code below is modified from the DEMO's BaseDemoActivity.java (I mentioned above).

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION:
    if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK) && (data != null) && (data.getExtras() != null ))
      // user selected account, get it
      String email = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
    else
      finish();    // user cancelled selection, an easy solution
    break;
  }
```

Comment: @lebenlechzer Another issue, #21610239 deals with this as well. If you follow it all the way to Github, there is some code I used to handle (maybe unrelated) problem.

Comment: Hi I am doing same thing but i am getting data null have any idea

Comment: Have no clue. Still, I would go and check the status of GooPlaySvcs on your device. Version mismatch? Clear cache? Zap GooPlaySvcs data (dangerous for other apps; I have a dedicated dev device that I can mess up).

Comment: Same problem, the picker comes up fine, and an account is selected (and I even store data there successfully) but the Intent data for this call back is null.  If I instead use "AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent" I do get the account name...

Comment: Is there any solution for the issue? it comes empty for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if user signed or not

   ```
   GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
       private void setupAuthorization() {
           GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                   new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                           .requestEmail() // add it if you want to user email 
                           .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                           .build();
           mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
           mGoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn().addOnSuccessListener(googleSignInAccount -> {googleSignInAccount.getEmail()}).addOnFailureListener(e -> {});
   }
   ```
2. If you want to get email and name after signing in

   @Override
                   protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
                       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                       switch (requestCode) {
                           case REQUEST_CODE_DRIVE_SIGN_IN:
                               Log.i(TAG, "Sign in request code");
                           // Called after user is signed in.
                           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                               Log.i(TAG, "Signed in successfully.");
                               // Use the last signed in account here since it already have a Drive scope.
       GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this); 
       googleSignInAccount.getEmail();
                               mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
                               // Build a drive resource client.
                               mDriveResourceClient =
                                       Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
                           }
                           break;}}

The details could be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in#configure_google_sign-in_and_the_googleapiclient_object)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **data** Intent is always *null* :(

```
public void startResolutionForResult(Activity var1, int var2) throws SendIntentException {
    if(this.hasResolution()) {
        var1.startIntentSenderForResult(this.mPendingIntent.getIntentSender(), var2, (Intent)null, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

This code is from ConnectionResult.class