# Sharing credentials between Drive SDK v.2 and Google Drive Android API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-api-client

here's yet another pit a fell into when trying to implement the new [Google Drive Android API (GDAA)](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started):
**Activity A** of my app needs functionality not supported by GDAA, so I resort to using the original [Google Drive SDK v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/) per the statement [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth).:

> In some cases, applications may need to use the Google Drive web
>   service to access additional features or access broader scopes than
>   what is available in the Google Drive Android API. In these cases,
>   your application must use the Google APIs Client Library for Java.

The auth sequence is standard:

```
...
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE);
credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
...
```

The authentication / authorization with DRIVE_FILE scope is succesful.

In **Activity B**, I use the GDAA, going through the standard sequence

1. x = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)....build();
2. x.connect()
3. onConnectionFailed()
4. startResolutionForResult()

and this is where the problem appears. The user already went through account selection and authorization in Activity A, but GDAA does not know anything about it. This causes a new account selection dialog to pop up again. So the question is:
Is there a way to pass the initialized credentials to GDAA without bugging the user again (scope's the same)?
 If the app needs to use both Google [Drive SDK v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)  and GDAA (as will probably be the case for any, but most trivial app), showing the account selection dialog more than once will certainly be a showstopper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When building a new GoogleApiClient, you can explicitly set an account name.

```
x = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
       .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
       .setAccountName(accountName)...
```

Since the application is authorized for the account, it will automatically connect.

Comment: Thank you. That was quick. Incidentally, your answer came as I completed implementation the other way around, i.e.
1/ starting with GDAA authorization 2/ pulling email from authorization result 3/using it in SDK v2

But this solution allows to keep my original flow.

Comment: Your answer made me think about this: In the DriveSDKv2 I had both GoogleAccountCredential setter (setSelectedAccountName) and getter (getSelectedAccountName) available. With GDAA I use a hack like this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501829/retrieve-account-name-with-the-new-google-drive-api/21517450#21517450
And keep the 'email' around. Did I put my foot in mouth by answering it without knowing about a getter method in GDAA?

Comment: There is no getter method in GDAA, but we can quickly fix this on the next releases. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thank you, I added a consolidation answer in another (essentially the same) topic,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610239/how-do-i-switch-accounts-under-the-new-google-drive-android-api/21641459#21641459
cleaning the mess I made. And the 'getter' isn't really needed.